# How to graceful restart apache httpd services on RHEL7?

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf, rhel, rhel7

When I am trying to graceful restart apache it gives me error as mentioned below.

```
[root@green vagrant]# sudo systemctl status httpd.service
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-10-12 10:28:45 CDT; 21h ago
 Main PID: 3757 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service

Oct 12 10:28:45 green.northamerica.cerner.net httpd[3757]: AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
Oct 12 10:28:45 green.northamerica.cerner.net systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 12 10:28:45 green.northamerica.cerner.net systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 12 10:28:45 green.northamerica.cerner.net systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 12 10:53:43 green.northamerica.cerner.net systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
Oct 12 10:53:59 green.northamerica.cerner.net systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
Oct 13 08:14:50 green.northamerica.cerner.net systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

**More logs if it helps:**

**This is how it is mentioned in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
# Modules to load
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

**This is content of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf:**

```
# Select the MPM module which should be used by uncommenting exactly
# one of the following LoadModule lines:

# prefork MPM: Implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

# worker MPM: Multi-Processing Module implementing a hybrid
# multi-threaded multi-process web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html
#
# LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

# event MPM: A variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming
# threads only for connections with active processing
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html
#
# LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

After this configuration it gives me below error,

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-10-13 08:37:48 CDT; 26min ago
  Process: 8505 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8493 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 8493 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Comment: Well, the error message is clear: "Configuration error: No MPM loaded."

Comment: I have tried to and checked my /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf file and it looks it has that. Do you have any I idea how to solve that error?

Comment: Well, you _could_ start by posting the content of that file and how it is included, so that we can take a look. Also whether those modules are actually installed. And you could place an obvious syntax error in that file to check if it indeed gets processed.